# Creating a custom warning for my library. Subclass Warning or UserWarning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

I am writing a library and I want to warn users about some potentially-hazardous situations that are not "bad enough" to warrant crashing their program with an exception.

I am planning to implement my own warning class for this purpose. Should I subclass `Warning`, or `UserWarning`?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-categories) aren't really clear on this point. It seems like I should subclass `Warning`, and leave `UserWarning` for the "default" case of a user just typing `warnings.warn()`, but I'm not sure if there is a particular convention, rule, or generally-accepted practice on this subject.